# Why i cannot get in the database? jacky @ local host Password : NO

Tags: python, html, sql, flask, phpmyadmin

[image: code]

Why i cannot get in the database? jacky @ local host Password : NO

Comment: Share your code here, not an image of it please

Comment: You've tagged the phpMyAdmin, but this error doesn't seem to be related to that program. Are you running your query through the phpMyAdmin interface? I'm a little confused what the relevance is.

Answer (score 1):

Your flask configuration is wrong.

```
app.config['MySQL_USER'] = 'root'
```

Here the key `MySQL_USER` is the wrong key. You need to use the key `'MYSQL_USER'` (case is important here)

```
app.config['MYSQL_USER'] = 'root'
```

(same for the other config items)

See the [docs](https://flask-mysqldb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#configuration)

Right now, your flask app is using the default credentials, which happen to be your computer username & no password (hence the error)